# Simplify: $\frac{d}{dy}\int_{x\in I}g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

$x\in [0,1]$, $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R_+$ is a smooth mapping, $f(x)=y$

Let $y$ be a regular value. Define the inversion set $f^{-1}(y)=X$ s.t.  $ f(x)=y \ \forall x\in X$. Then $X$ is of dimension zero.

Rank (sort) $x\in X$ in the order $\{x_1,x_2...\}$ s.t. $x_1<x_2<...$

Define $(0,x_1)\cup(x_2,x_3)\cup...=I$

(I am not sure if it is mathematically rigorous to say "rank" like this. If you know the formal representation please let me know.)

Is it possible to simplify:

$$\frac{d}{dy}\int_{x\in I}g(x)dx?$$ where $g$ is a smooth real function.

---

If $x$ is the only element of $X$ (i.e. $f^{-1}(y)$ is unique) then the problem becomes simple: $\frac{d}{dy}\int_{x\in I}g(x)dx=g(x)/f'(x)$

Comment: Questions, questions,.... : 1. do you mean $X=f^{-1}(\{y\})$ ?. 2. is $y_1=y$ ? 3. What do you mean, when you say " rank $x \in X $ as $ \{x_1,x_2,..\}$" ...., questions,....

Comment: @Fred What I meant is to sort all $x\in X$ s.t. $x_1<x_2<...$. I am not sure how to formally present this process, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $y$ is a regular value of $f$, we should have that $X$ is discrete, i.e., every point of $X$ is isolated. In particular $X$ is finite and you can *enumerate* points of $X$ in ascending order.
2. There exist $n \geq 0$, a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ and smooth functions $\psi_i : V \to U_i$ for $i = 1, \cdots, n$ such that $U_i$ are disjoint open subsets of $I$ and

   $$f^{-1}(\{y'\}) = \{ \psi_1(y') < \cdots < \psi_n(y')\}$$

   for each $y' \in V$. That is, $\psi_i$ are local inverse of $f$. Assuming that your construction is given by

   $$ I = \begin{cases}
   (0, \psi_1(y)) \cup \cdots \cup (\psi_n(y), 1) & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
   (0, \psi_1(y)) \cup \cdots \cup (\psi_{n-1}(y), \psi_n(y)) & \text{if $n$ is odd}
   \end{cases}, $$

   i.e. collecting only odd-th subintervals of the open set $(0,1)\setminus f^{-1}(\{y\})$ and taking union on them, then it follows that

   $$ \frac{d}{dy} \int_{I} g(x) \, dx
   = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} g(\psi_i(y))\psi_i'(y)
   = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} \frac{g(\psi_i(y))}{f'(\psi_i(y))}. $$

   In your notation, $x_i = \psi_i(y)$ and so it is slightly more succinctly written as

   $$ \frac{d}{dy} \int_{I} g(x) \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} \frac{g(x_i)}{f'(x_i)}. $$

Comment: Thank you so much. Did you assumed that $g(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot differentiate an object with respect to $y$ which does not depend in a definite way on $y$. Write your integral in a way which shows the dependence on $y$. You'll see that this is a difficult task! In fact $\int_{x\in I} g(x)\>dx$ is a number; it could be $=\pi$.

Comment: Interval $I$ is dependent on $y$. Sorry if my notations are bad.